# call to api from xamarin dosen't works

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have added a PCL project to Visual studio from where i have created ViewModel Class and i want to call a request to my WebApi project.
This is my ViewModel From where makes the call to api.

```
public async Task<int> InsertRecord()
        {

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:27803/api/XamApp/InsertRecord/1");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
return 0;

}
```

On the receiving End I have WebApi method that receives that parameter.

```
 [HttpGet]    
        public HttpResponseMessage InsertRecord(string id)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage rspSite = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            //db.tblRegistration.Add(_reg);
            //db.SaveChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK,"test");  
            //return rspSite;
        }
```

But issue is that i didn't get any thing in response and also control doesn't goes to that api method.
It is android application can be open in Visual Studio and Xamarin.
Please give me appropriate soloutio. if any kind of extension or is to be added let me know.

Comment: Why the `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();`?

Comment: ok if i remove that again it doesn't work

Comment: What exactly happens when you send the rquest? Do you receive an error response from the server or does `SendAsync` fail entirely and there is no HTTP message at all?

Comment: application breaks with an Unhandled Exception:     and in Output it throws the following error that "The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 "

Comment: So obviously there's something wrong with your request. What kind of exception do you get, and, most important, what does the exception message say?

Comment: Could it be you simply forgot to start the API application, or you have a typo somewhere? Can you call the Web API with another client (e.g. browser)?